# CodedUI Test 'Refreshing Page' error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests, automated-tests

My Automated test fail when it will fill out a HTML edibox,this is the error message:

Assert.Fail failed. The web page could not be accessed. If the page is refreshing, please wait until the page refreshes and then perform actions on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more descriptive.

If the page hasn't loaded yet and its trying to type you could manually put in a delay of say 5 seconds, try this

```
Playback.Wait(5000);
```

Comment: I'm already try this, the problem is that the page has already loaded before error.

Comment: is the page opening in a new tab or window?

Comment: I Solved the problem, the problem was that, when test change to EditBox field the page refresh silently. Thank you for help!